# Wiring of mains AC through relay

Tags: relay, ac, wiring

Is it correct that if I would like to control 4 AC appliance/lighting power points, then the AC-Live wire is put through the relay, and a common AC-Neutral is used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that would work.  Depending on the power of these appliances and your local jurisdiction, you may be required to switch both the hot and neutral with DPST (double pole single throw) relays.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Is switching both hot/live and neutral considered a safer practice ?

Comment: @icarus: It shouldn't matter when everything is working right.  However, stuff happens, and then switching both lines can be a good thing.  If this is high power that runs off of 220V, like a dryer or electric range, then both lines have to be switched since both are hot.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Can you please explain how both the lines are hot? Even with a high power device, if the SPST is placed on the live wire, shouldn't that be sufficient to break the pathway of current?

Comment: @Ankit: Ideally, breaking one of the two hot lines turns of the device.  However, as I said before, stuff happens.  For safety reasons, it's a good idea to switch all lines that are hot.

Comment: @OlinLathrop. Got it. Thanks for the explanation. I was debating between SPST or DPST for my load switching and hence the question.

Comment: @Ankit: In the US, it is common for power companies to supply two wires which are 120V with respect to neutral, in opposite phases.  Devices that need 220V are connected between the two "hot" wires.  Switching only one wire would stop a device from operating, but would not make its interior wiring safe to touch.  Having the interior wiring of a device "live" while the device isn't operating is more dangerous than when it is operating, since people may be more prone to assume the former is "safe".